# Google Smart Home Action not visible in Home Control section

Tags: google-smart-home

I made some changes to Authorization URL and Token URL in Accounting Linking. After that when I enable Test l, the action with [test] prefix didn't appear under Home Control section in Google Home app. The app is logged in with the same account as the account which I used to create the action. To add up, the action is already being deployed in production. I'm facing this issue when I updated the Account Linking settings and enabled it for Testing. I've also tried undeploying the previous version of the action. But still it didn't appear in the Home Control. Due to this I can't submit my action for review.

Help me out to fix this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you disable current testing and then re-enable testing

Comment: Yes I did that too. I received mail from the support team to submit my action for a review so that they could help me test the updated configuration. Thanks for your support! @Nick Feller.

Answer (score 0):

Once your Action is deployed to production, the project will no longer reflect console changes to the test agent until those changes are submitted and reviewed. The recommended way to work around this constraint is to create a second project in the Actions console that you can use to test/validate your change.

When you're ready to submit the updates to production, you can follow the steps outlined to updating your existing production project in [Launching your smart home Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/launching).

Comment: I'll try your suggestion @Devunwired. Thank you for your support!